# Declaracion de variable en Java(Netbeans)

Tags: java, contador

Ayuda por favor, necesito crear una variable para hacer un contador, pero necesito que esa variable entera pueda ser llamada en todos los Jframes de mi package, he intentado de algunos modos y aun no lo consigo
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar la variable de modo publica para que puedar ser accesible desde otras clases que esten dentro del mismo paquete, por ejemplo:

public int num;

Answer (score 0):

Hola Te recomiendo que crees un Getter y uses este para obtener el valor, ahora si pones mas en contexto lo que quieres hacer por ahi te podamos ayudar mas. Saludos

Comment: Aun soy principiante en java, ¿podrias ayudarme con la linea de codigo para la delcaracion de esa variable?, y en este caso ¿podria seguir usando el x++; para el contador? TE LO AGRADECERIA MUCHISIMO :(